# Presenting Game Center problems

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I am trying to add High Scores in my game, and I don't know why i can't present the Leader boards. I can connect the user and send data. But can't see it.

My Game its in Cocos2d. But my MENU isn't when the user click on Play CCDirector Start

My main windows structure its:
-Navigation Contoller
  - Menu -Ui View controller
    - Navigation Item

I try to do it like a navigation and push it and crash. Also add it as subview. And crash. My leader boards code

```
- (IBAction)showLeader:(id)sender {
    if ([self isGameCenterAvailable]) {
        GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

        if (leaderboardController != nil) {
            leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;

            //[self presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

-(BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable {
    // Check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API.
    Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

    // The device must be running running iOS 4.1 or later.
    NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

    return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}
```

What could i do?

And another question. Could i put my own effect to present the leader bords scores? Or apple will reject it?

I am trying to do a small framework. So i don't need to codify allot in the Menu Game etc..

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do this.

```
menu2Game = [[Menu2Game alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu2Game" bundle:nil];
            menu2Game.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

            [self.view addSubview:menu2Game.view];
            [menu2Game presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
```

menu2Game its a clean View Controller. Maybe I can create a view controller temporally here. But I need to save it somewhere so i could dismiss it.

It work. But i am trying to do it in a landscape